# in putty i have a file that is like this #xxx.c#

Tags: c, putty

While using Putty.I have a file in my directory and  I want to remove it , but the rm command doesn't work.and it's in white.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a backup file from your editor (sorry not sure what), but you can remove them using the following:

```
$ rm \#*.c\#
```

Comment: possible emacs -- emacs uses these files for autosave info

Answer (score 1):

`#` is a comment delimiter in `bash` and probably any shell you're likely to use. Try escaping it with single quotes:

```
rm '#xxx.c#'
```